# Screen reader Android app that sends text as an API request

Tags: android, api, internet, screen-reader

If I have an API where I can give it a text and it will return an audio file reading the text. I'm not an Android developer, so I'm not able to develop a TTS service from scratch. Hence, I need a ready-made Android app that can capture the text from the screen and pass the text from the current screen to this API. Optionally play the returned response audio.

I anticipate a non-root solution for this. It may be an open-source app that code can be adapted to use this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just regular text (not OCR) then [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) is an example of a tool that can do it (and much more) prett well:

- reading text on screen can be done with e.g. [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) addon and its UI queries
- text can be stored in [variables](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/variables.html)
- HTTP requests are also [built-in](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/ah_http_request.html)

Comment: Does Tasker has some plugin to play the returned audio data which will be in b64decode format and should be decoded to wav file format?

Comment: That's a different question which I'm unable to answer as I'm not sure how the decoding process works. But it can play sounds, yes. I think it had some base64 related functions too, but I don't remember if the were built-in or custom.

Comment: Thanks @Destroy666, if you can add more details on the steps above. I downloaded Tasker and AutoInput, but it's not easy application to configure from first time.

Comment: This is more of software recommendations site and I can't even provide accurate description without knowing details of implementation, but if you ask for specific problem at https://android.stackexchange.com/ and link it to me, I could help with that.

Comment: Here is the question on https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252478 with detailed steps

Comment: @RamiSedhom it's removed, so I assume you got it working?

Comment: @Destory666 yes, thanks to your guidelines